# Erro Pagina Dashboard PHP - Cache limiter session start

Tags: php, session, login

Estou com problemas em meu site, no netbeans o site funcionou perfeitamente, porém ao fazer hospedagem no site br.000webhost.com para testes, ocorre que em alguma paginas recebo a seguinte mensagem:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /storage/ssd1/343/4724343/public_html/dashboard.php:1) in /storage/ssd1/343/4724343/public_html/dashboard.php on line 6

fiz buscas na internet mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse.

Não estou conseguindo revolver. abaixo o código de abertura de sessão

```
<?php
// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION))
session_start(); // Essa é a linha na qual o erro se refere

$nivel_necessario = 1;

// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID']) OR ( $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] < 
$nivel_necessario)) {
// Destrói a sessão por segurança
session_destroy();
// Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvendo o problema de "headers already sent"**

m erro que muito programador iniciante acaba se deparando aí é o famoso “Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by…” ou “Warning: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by…” e nem sempre é fácil de descobrir o que se fazer para resolver esse erro (que na verdade não é erro, é um warning, um aviso).

**Antes de resolver o problema você precisa entender por que esse erro acontece..**

Por que “headers already sent”?
Toda página na internet está hospedada em servidor e o seu navegador “pede” ao servidor da página, o resultado (HTML) da página com endereço X… Aí o servidor move os seus pauzinhos, interpreta os arquivos e começa a te responder, enviando um cabeçalho de resposta (o famoso header) esse cabeçalho contém informações sobre a codificação da página, tamanho da página, tempo de duração do cache, hora da ultima atualização e tudo que seja relevante, sobre uma página da Internet, para um navegador.

Depois do envio do header o servidor envia o HTML da página toda e o seu browser começa a montar ela pra você.

Quando você lê “headers already sent” no aviso, significa que o seu servidor já enviou o header e APÓS esse envio, você está tentando criar ou alterar alguma informação que deva ser enviada no header.

Por exemplo, os cookies: são definidos antes do envio do header e enviados para o navegador DENTRO do header… Se você tentar criar ou alterar um cookie depois que o header foi enviado você receberá o aviso de erro.

Outro exemplo que segue a mesma lógica dos Cookies é a Sessão, que são como cookies encriptados que ficam salvos no servidor. Toda sessão possui um cookie identificador (session cookie) que é enviado para o visitante a fim de identificá-lo e manter os valores da sua sessão… Se você tentar criar ou remover algum valor da sessão depois do envio do header vai receber a mensagem de erro “Warning: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by…”.

**E quando raios eu enviei o header? Eu não fiz nada!**
Realmente, se você não usa nenhuma função de manipulação de headers, você não fez nada e está recebendo esse erro… Mas há uma explicação pra isso!

Em se tratando de PHP (e acredito que o mesmo ocorra com todas as outras linguagens WEB que precisam ser lidas por um parseador), o header começa a ser enviado logo que você insira o primeiro caractere no HTML final da página… Seja fora do código PHP com HTML normal, seja dentro do código PHP com um echo ou print().

```
<?php
$numero = 3;
$dobro = $numero * 2; // 6
```

Imagine que, na linha 1, antes do “" houvesse um espaço... Tudo que está fora do "” é HTML, então um espaço ali seria como o 1° caractere do HTML causando o envio do header… Qualquer função de sessão/cookie/etc. dentro do bloco de PHP iria causar o erro.

```
<?php
echo 'Olá mundo';
session_start(); // Inicio de sessão depois do envio do header?! Problema!
```

Esse é outro caso clássico.. O desenvolvedor tentou criar uma sessão (que definirá um cookie de sessão novo) após enviar o header (por causa do echo).

**Tá, e como eu resolvo?**
Lembra que eu disse que você não fez nada e ainda tá recebendo o erro? Pra resolver o problema é a mesma coisa: nada (além do normal) precisa ser feito… Você só precisa colocar todo código que trabalhe com headers (sessões, cookies, redirecionamentos e etc.) antes de enviar qualquer caractere pro HTML… Nada de tentar definir/criar um cookie ou sessão depois de enviar um “Seja bem vindo!” ou enviar o  do seu site.

Cookies e sessões, bem como os redirecionamentos e encriptação de conteúdo devem ser enviados, criados, definidos e modificados ANTES de qualquer HTML… Afinal, todo o HTML pode e deve depender desses fatores.

E antes que você comente dizendo “mas meu site precisa enviar HTML antes de criar um cookie!” eu te respondo “erro de planejamento”. :)

Espero que menos pessoas tenham esse problema a partir de hoje!